# Display LVM information in Linux redhat

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

How to display Logical Volume full name with volume group and their size and  mount point? All above information are displayed horizontally.

Example:

```
LV                VG          Size    Mountpoint
/dev/vg1/lv1      vg1         100M    /data
```

Answer (score 1):

The first three are available from `lvs`. The last is available from `mount`. You can combine them with a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
echo LV VG Size Mountpoint
sudo lvs --noheadings -o lv_path,vg_name,lv_size | while read lv vg size; do
  echo -n "$lv $vg $size "
  mount | while read dev on path rest; do
    [[ "$lv" -ef "$dev" ]] || continue
    echo -n "$path"
    break
  done
  echo
done
) | column -t
```

This produces the following output on my system:

```
LV                        VG         Size    Mountpoint
/dev/vg_gargan/lv_aron    vg_gargan  64.00g  /home/aron
/dev/vg_gargan/lv_fedora  vg_gargan  21.50g  /
/dev/vg_gargan/lv_data    vg_gargan  21.00g  /data
/dev/vg_gargan/lv_swap    vg_gargan  2.00g
```

Hope that helps!